# Implement custom UITabBar to multiple UIViewController's

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to include a tab bar, with 4-5 tab bar items on it, to multiple view controllers of my app and will work as menu to jump between views (Map, About, Favourites etc.).

I have created on Storyboard a UITabBar item and set its Bar item's tags. Because the same tab bar will be used on several other view controllers (Main, View2, View3 etc.) I've decided to create a class that extends UITabBar. This will help me to customise the bar later. The UITabBar object in Storyboard is now an object of this class (BottomTabBar).

My question is, how I can detect when a bar item has been tapped?

In addition, because I am not familiar with TabBar, if you have any general guides or tips that will help me during development please share them with me.

**BottomTabBar.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BottomTabBar : UITabBar <UITabBarDelegate>

@end
```

**BottomTabBar.m**

```
#import "BottomTabBar.h"

@implementation BottomTabBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

    NSLog(@"Tabbed!");
}

@end
```

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BottomTabBar.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *slideshow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *scroll;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet BottomTabBar *bottomBar;


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorials and source codes for custom tab bar.

[Custom tabbar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: So, I have to modify my class from `UITabBar` to `UITabBarController`?

Comment: The problem is that, I do not want Tab Bar Controller, just simple Tab Bar to include it in an existing View Controller

Comment: take just a look of this url

Comment: My mistake! I was doing it on wrong way. I was including the delegate in BottomTabBar class instead of the class I want it to appear. Now I can detect if a tab has been pressed and the tag #. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have another coding question. I have 2-3 ViewControllers where I would like to include the UITabBar. The way I found at the moment requires, 1) to include `UITabBarDelegate` on every one of these ViewControllers and 2) to include `didSelectItem` on every one of these ViewControllers. The actions of each TabBarItem most of times will remain the same everywhere. In addition, I would like to keep selected item even if move from one view to another. There is any way to dispose all this duplicate code?

Answer (score 0):

This guide is really good:

http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/

Notice there is also a second part there.